# Docker-compose in multiple projects same services different container but shared volumes and data are in wrong projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I have many ongoing website projects, each with their own docker-compose.yml. They basically use the same services (PHP, MySQL, Nginx, etc).

I do use unique COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME in .env for each project and they have dynamic container names :

```
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: '${APP_NAME}_mysql'
```

```
/projects
    /project1
         /.env
         /docker-compose.yml
    /project2
         /.env
         /docker-compose.yml
```

My problem is the following :
database created for project1 is visible in the mysql of the project2 and vice versa
rebuilding or destroying mysql for project2, destroys it for project1 also, so I lose database.
this becomes a nightmare because I have a lot more than 2 projects.

More info: it also happens that some projects are in PHP7.x and others in PHP8.x, and when I edit my Dockerfile for the PHP service and change the version and rebuild, than all projects are now on the new PHP version, which obviously might break them.

Environment : windows10pro + wsl2 Ubuntu

Adding docker compose file for completeness:

```
    # For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    #PHP Service
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: digitalocean.com/php
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
        restart: unless-stopped
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:${HOST_GATEWAY}" 
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
            - ./docker/php/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - mailhog

    #Nginx Service
    webserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}_webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
            - ./docker/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
        networks:
            - sail
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"            
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - /docker/mysql-dump:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}_pma
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
        ports:
            - '8282:80'
        networks:
            - sail  
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}_redis
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}_mailhog
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

Adding Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
# COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libicu-dev \
    g++ \
    libxml2-dev \
    libonig-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install vim nano

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install default-mysql-client

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY docker /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www docker /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?  Compose can set the various objects' names on its own and one simple approach could be to just delete `container_name:` and similar settings on volumes and networks.

Comment: @DavidMaze added the compose file for example.

Comment: The problematic services in the other compose files are exactly the same? i.e. are you using the same volume entries?

Comment: I'd assume the issue is a missing `.` on the path spec of the `mysql` service in the bottom composefile. As you can see, both containers' mysql data contents are bound to the same path on the host, `/docker/mysql-dump`

Comment: @DavidMaze I did add the container_name specifically because i faced the issue of different project using the same container. But I'll try again your proposal.

Comment: @WerWet the volumes have the same 'relative' path, like this : - /docker/mysql-dump:/var/lib/mysql  Maybe that is the issue.? How could I personalize them?

Comment: @SIMULATAN I don't know why for this volume, it was throwing an error with the dot and the container never started. By removing the dot it worked.

Comment: Well, that's the reason for the failure then. You fixed one issue by opening up another one. `/docker/...` is never a relative path, just using that and removing the dot is not a fix. Please share the error you experienced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that your databases share their data in your setup. The only way (ignoring networking) that the containers could share data is via volumes and there is the catch. The '*volumes*', as in the `-v`/`--volume` parameter of `docker` command or the docker compose `volumes` property, are really two different things:

> **Volumes** are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem. Volumes are the best way to persist data in Docker.

> **Bind mounts** may be stored anywhere on the host system. They may even be important system files or directories. Non-Docker processes on the Docker host or a Docker container can modify them at any time.

From [docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/storage/).

The former one, the "real" *volumes*, are shared on the host.<sup>[1]</sup> So if another compose file define volume with the same name it points to the same storage space.

That's the reason why the redis data are shared. Oddly enough, as pointed out by the @SIMULATAN in the Q comments, the mysql uses an absolute path therefore the data are shared via *bind mounting* to a common directory in the host system.

The solution is either to *bind mount* the data using a paths to unique locations (typically relative paths) or you could use the *volumes* with names that aren't shared where you don't want. There is pros and cons listed in [the already mentioned docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/).

If you go with the second option, it could be useful that the volume names could be even set "dynamicly":

```yaml
volumes:
  mysql:
    name: "${MY_VAR}" #overrides the name `data` specified in the line above
```

<sup>[1] The docs said you could define anonymous volume, which could not be shared as they don't have predefined name</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was busy recently, I'll explore your options and get back with how it went.